# Seague to NavigationController failing on real device but not on simulator?

Tags: objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, segue, uistoryboardsegue

This is my code to seague to another UINavigationController:

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    static NSString *segueIdentifier = @"ShowDetails";

    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:segueIdentifier]) {

        UINavigationController *navigationController = [segue destinationViewController];

        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];


        DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;

        if ([detailViewController respondsToSelector:@selector(setGameID:)]) {
            detailViewController.selectedGameIdNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%ld", (long)indexPath.row];
            detailViewController.selectedSection = [self.sectionNames objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
        }
    }
}
```

When running with a simulator everything works fine. No errors and the data is being passed to the next NavigationController. However now when i try it with a real device it fails on this code:

```
DetailViewController *detailViewController = (DetailViewController *)navigationController.topViewController;
```

with the error:

```
-[DetailViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d649ca0
2015-02-27 00:06:09.446 TabbedTutorial[1029:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[DetailViewController topViewController]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14d649ca0'
```

I have no idea why it works on simulator but not on device. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When you call a selector on instance of method that doesn't belong to this instance.

Answer (score 0):

If this question is still unsloved, then it might be happening ASFAIK on diffrent devices there is different hierarchy.

So, u might want to try

```
     DetailViewController *controller ;

   if([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[UINavigationController class] ]  )
   {
       controller = (DetailViewController *) [[segue destinationViewController] topViewController];
   }
    else
    {
        controller = [segue destinationViewController];
    }

    // pass data 
}
```

Hope this helps